# Type hinting a dictionary with a given set of keys and values

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-3.8, typeddict

Suppose I have an Enum class in Python:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = "a"
    B = "b"
```

I have a function that is returning for each of the possible (two in this case) enum values a given type: suppose for both of them it is returning a DataFrame. I want to type hint, and for this I was using `TypedDict` in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import TypedDict

class ReturnedType(TypedDict):
    MyEnum.A.value: pd.DataFrame
    MyEnum.B.value: pd.DataFrame
```

and then:

```
def foo(...) -> ReturnedType
```

but apparently `TypedDict` does not accept defining field names with other variables and this mypy checks to fail.

What is the most pythonic way to type hint such a function in this case?

Here is a MWE:

```
from typing import Dict, TypedDict
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'

class MyClass(TypedDict):
    """The class defines the shape of the dictionary output
    by any RoadCodec"""

    MyEnum.A.value: int
    MyEnum.B.value: float

def foo() -> MyClass:
    res: MyClass = {MyEnum.A.value: 3, MyEnum.B.value: 4.4}
```

By launching mypy checks I get the error

> Invalid statement in TypedDict definition; expected
> "field_name: field_type"  [misc]

Also note that I am running under Python3.8 so StrEnum is not available

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? You don't need Pandas to reproduce the issue; you could just use a builtin like `int` instead. And `def foo(...)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Use an [`enum.StrEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) for `MyEnum`, ditch `.value` and use the enum member directly, then do `foo(...) -> dict[MyEnum, pd.DataFrame]`.

Comment: @dROOOze Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead :)

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to return a different type based on the enum value? Or is it always the same?

Comment: @wjandrea I've provided an example

Comment: @dROOOze `StrEnum` is available in later versions of Python3.8, I can't use it

Comment: You can subclass `enum.Enum` with `str` to get the same effect (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#notes): `class MyEnum(str, enum.Enum)`

Comment: @bfontaine Thanks for the feedback. I've modified my question trying to give an example. From the function, I want to return a TypedDict or dictionary whose keys are the strings defined by the Enum type, and the corresponding values are the ones specified. I

Comment: @roschach Just to add, `StrEnum` is also provided by [`aenum`](https://github.com/ethanfurman/aenum), whose author is the maintainer of the stdlib `enum`.

Comment: Do you consider a `dataclasss`? Along `ReturnedType = make_dataclass('ReturnedType', [(MyEnum.A.value, pd.DataFrame), (MyEnum.A.value, pd.DataFrame)])`. However, it will no longer be a dictionary.

Comment: @Ka I might, but on a first check I am getting ` Property "value" defined in "Enum" is read-only`

Answer (score 1):

sadly there's no pretty way to achieve this.

There exists some cumbersome way though. I haven't tested this with mypy yet, but at least with pylance/pyright/vscode this works:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Dict, Union, overload, Literal
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = "a"
    B = "b"

class ReturnedType(Dict[MyEnum, Union[int, str]]):

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.A]) -> int:
        ...
    
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.B]) -> str:
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, __key: MyEnum) -> Union[int, str]:
        return super()[__key]
    
    @overload
    def get(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.A]) -> Union[int, None]:
        ...

    @overload
    def get(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.A], __default: int) -> int:
        ...

    @overload
    def get(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.B]) -> Union[str, None]:
        ...

    @overload
    def get(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.B], __default: str) -> str:
        ...

    def get(self, __key: MyEnum, __default: Union[int, str, None] = None) -> Union[int, str, None]:
        return super().get(__key, __default)

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.A], __value: int):
        ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, __key: Literal[MyEnum.B], __value: str):
        ...
    
    def __setitem__(self, __key: MyEnum, __value: Union[int, str]):
        super()[__key] = __value
    
def foo() -> ReturnedType:
    rv = ReturnedType()
    rv[MyEnum.A] = 3
    rv[MyEnum.B] = "hello"
    return rv

d: int = foo()[MyEnum.A]
a: str = foo()[MyEnum.A] # incompatible!
```